# How to go back to default xml layout interface?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml, eclipse-adt

i don't how how this happens.. but i don't know how to use this format..
i just wanna go back to the default layout option in which you can drag n drop buttons,text fields and in back-end coding is automatically created..
i just don't find any option and don't know how to Google the problem..
thank you

Comment: You mean you don't see the "Graphical Layout" Tab at the bottom of the xml layout file view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When You are in Coding part and you want to go to Graphical layout you can press **ALT + PAGE UP**.

This will go to Graphical layout where you can Drag and Drop.

Hope this is what you are Searching for.

EDITED :

Right Click on that file --> open with --> Android layout Editor.

Comment: http://goo.gl/B6e8l
 see this.. this thing is coming instead of that graphical layout.. otherwise i know that

Comment: Dev: Thankx.. thats all i wanted

Comment: And can you tell me how to make it default.. i hav to open every file with open with...

Comment: i think the circle of the option says that it is default and as you select that option once it will be set as default.

Comment: no.. its not default.. i even restarted the eclipse.. even then it doesn't showed as default

Comment: don't knw what's wrong der, but i selected android animator editor and then all other opens in android animator editor.

Comment: btw what are "circle of option" and "android animater"
P.S: I am a newbie

Comment: those are options provided to me when selecting open with.

Comment: I found it
Go to Window->Preferences->General->Editors->File Associations...  then select ***xml** from **file types**..  then **android layout manager** from **associated editors** & the press **default**..  neways thankx for your help